# What does, or could, the phrase こんなヤツはこうだ！ mean?

Tags: translation

My understanding is that it literally means "that guy is like this", but I don't think I understand the connotation.

Comment: Any context you'd like to add?

Comment: Whenever there's a こうだ、 これだ etc etc referring to a "this", the context is key.

Answer (score 4):

> こんなヤツはこうだ！

Usually, it'd mean something like 「こんなヤツはこうしてやる！」 *lit:* "To someone like this, I'll do *this*!" (*this* would usually be something unfavorable, such as hitting, punching, smacking, etc...) You'd use this kind of phrase when giving someone お仕置き(a punishment).